# Accessing horizontal JSON data in Javascript

Tags: json

For currency exchange rates, Yahoo has a very rapid alternative to YQL in: http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json

This is great except that the JSON format is a little unfamiliar to me. it seems I have to do something like
parsedjson.list.resources[3].resource.fields.price
to pull out the USD/VND exchange rate. Instead of accessing by index I would like to search by the name field, i.e. some function that when i input "USD/VND" returns the price just as above, but without me having to look up and hardcode the index.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for helping a newbie.

Comment: Why is it "unfamiliar"?  JSON is JSON.  It appears to be correct syntax.  What else could be "unfamiliar"??

Comment: well i mean it is unfamiliar to me. normally I would use something like parsedjson.list.USDVND.resource.fields.price to pull something up, so I wouldnt have to know the index. In here, the identifier "USD/VND" is contained on the same level as the price itself. so I cannot use that method if I don't want to hardcode the index. does that make sense?

Comment: You write a loop and loop through the resources array.  If you need to search it repeatedly build a map over the resource entries.  And, depending on your platform (which you fail to specify) there may be a generalized platform scheme for searching map/list structures, saving you a half-dozen lines of code for the loop.